# Upload Excel File with Fetch() Convert To JSON in Memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, reactjs, multer

Looking for best practices on handling Excel File Upload in React/Node and converting to JSON with additional form data.

**Requirements:**

- Post includes form data in addition to Excel File
- Handle Excel File on server with Node.js and Multer in Memory ie., multer.memoryStorage() **(Not Saving File To Server)**
- Convert Excel data to JSON, then append JSON data with additional form data before sending to MongoDB.
- I will also need to process through NGINX on production, which may be an issue uploading the Excel file.  Not an issue in Dev without NGINX.

**Current working solution on Dev with React/Redux and Node.js:**

1. Fetch() for post to server
2. Multer for handling post
3. xlsx_buffer_json https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx_buffer_json

   XLSX Buffer JSON Fix for missing cptable reference:

Had to add Externals object to webpack.config:

```js
       externals: [
         {
          './cptable': 'var cptable'
         },
       ]
```

**React Action Code**

```js
export function importAssets(assetData, importFile) {
    let systemAssetData = new FormData();
    systemAssetData.append('systemId', assetData.systemid);
    systemAssetData.append('productId', assetData.productid);
    systemAssetData.append('fileData', importFile);

    const config = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Accept':'application/json'},
        body: systemAssetData,
    };

   return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(requestImportAsset(assetData));

        return fetch('/asset/importAssets', config)
            .then(response =>
                response.json().then(assets => ({assets, response})),
            ).then(({assets, response}) => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    dispatch(requestImportAssetError(assets.message));
                    return Promise.reject(assets.message);
                }
                dispatch(requestImportAssetSuccess(assets));
                return 0;
            }).catch(err => console.log('Action Error: ', err)); 
    };
}
```

**Node/Express Route Code**

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var requestpromise = require('request-promise');
var multer  = require('multer');
var xlsxtojson = require("xlsx_buffer_json")
var path = require("path");
var storage = multer.memoryStorage();
var upload = multer({ storage: storage });

router.post('/importAssets', upload.single('fileData'),  (req, res) => {
    let config = req.app.get('config');
        try {
            xlsxtojson({
                input: req.file.buffer,
                output: null, 
                lowerCaseHeaders:true
            }, function(err,result){
                if(err) {
                    console.log('xlsxtojson error:  ' + err);
                    return res.json({error_code:1,err_desc:err, data: null});
                }
                result.push({"productid":req.body.productId});
                result.push({"systemid":req.body.systemId});
                
                //send result object JSON to API Server for insert into MongoDB
            });
        } catch (e){
            console.log('corrupt file error:  ' + e);
            res.json({error_code:1,err_desc:"Corupted excel file"});
        }
  res.status(200).send('Excel File Upload Succes')
});
```

While this works, it's not the cleanest solution in my mind.   I haven't seen a better working solution to date.

Any thoughts?